# What constant to select to compare result of fmod function

Tags: php, floating-point

I need to check if one float/double is multiple of another float/double. In integer it is easy

```
$isMultiple = $x % $y == 0;
```

but in floats/doubles it does not. The first problem is that floats has no % operator, so we must use fmod function, second bigger problem is that we cannot compare to zero but we must compare that number is less that some constant and I dont know how to select correct constant because I can always select numbers for which it does not works. For example if I select 0.00001, than it will still not works for some numbers:

```
$C = 0.00001;
$isMultiple1 = fmod(3.0, 2.0) < $C; // = false, which is correct
$isMultiple2 = fmod(1.39, 0.0001) < $C; // = false, which is not correct
```

In fact the proble is that result of `fmod(1.39, 0.0001)` is `9.9999999999836E-5` (0.000099999999999836) which is soo high for small constant, but if I select high constant it wont work for some another numbers.

How to select `$C` correctly or how to solve that problem differently which will universaly work for any numbers in PHP?

Comment: You could use a multiple of the second number, that is x is approximately a multiple of y if fabs( fmod(x,y)) < fraction*y

Comment: It is not true that you cannot compare to zero. Comparing a floating-point number `x` to zero yields true if and only if `x` is zero. Given two floating-point finite numbers `x` and `y`, `fmod(x, y) == 0` if and only if `x` is a multiple of `y`. However, it seems from your question that you do not want to determine whether a floating-point number `x` is a multiple of `y` but rather whether some real number *x* is a multiple of some real number *y*, and, to do this, you want to use the floating-point `x` and `y` that you have. In general, this is impossible…

Comment: … It is impossible because, given only `x` and `y`, we do not know what *x* and *y* really are, and therefore we cannot compute any functions of *x* and *y*. When we know that `x` and `y` **approximate** *x* and *y*, we can **approximate** functions of *x* and *y*, but only for functions that are continuous—functions where small changes to the inputs cause small changes to the outputs, like multiplication, addition, sine, and so on. For functions that are discontinuous, like `fmod`, where small changes to the inputs can cause large changes, having approximate `x` and `y` does not allow us to…

Comment: … compute what the function would be if we had the actual *x* and *y*. This is true of the function “Is *x* a multiple of *y*?” That function cannot be computed from approximations of *x* and *y*; it needs the actual values. Therefore, floating-point is the wrong format to use for this work.

Comment: Can you give more information on the purpose?

Comment: `0.0001` is *not* a multiple of `1.39` given `double` representation. 

`fmod(x,y) == 0.0` works for multiple detection.

It is just that `(double) 0.0001` and `(double) 1.39` do not have the arithmetic values of 0.0001 and 1.39.  Instead they have nearby values which do not form a multiple.

Answer (score -1):

This function checks whether a floating point value is an integer multiple of a floating point factor.

```
function isMultiple($product, $factor){
  $eps = 1.E-12;
  $rest = abs(fmod($product, $factor));
  if($rest < $eps) return true;
  return abs($rest-$factor) < $eps;
}

var_dump( isMultiple(3.0,2.0) );  //false
var_dump( isMultiple(1.39, 0.0001) );  //true
var_dump( isMultiple(1.39, 0.02) ); //false
```

Due to the limited accuracy of calculations with float values, the function only works within certain limits. For example, the factor must be a multiple of the floating point accuracy and the variable $eps.

Examples with wrong results

```
var_dump( isMultiple(1.1e-11, 0.2e-11) );  //bool(true)
var_dump( isMultiple(1.39, 0.00010000000000001) ); //bool(true)
```

**Update**

The following function does not use fmod and thus makes better use of the accuracy of float.

```
function isMultiple($value, $factor){
  $quot = $value/$factor;
  return abs(round($quot)-$quot)/$quot < 1.e-14;
}
```

All these tests give correct results

```
var_dump( isMultiple(3.0,2.0) );  //false
var_dump( isMultiple(1.39, 0.0001) );  //true
var_dump( isMultiple(1.39, 0.02) ); //false

var_dump( isMultiple(1.39, 0.0001000000000001) );  //bool(false)
var_dump( isMultiple(56185.047, 0.123) );  //bool(true)
var_dump( isMultiple(56185.04701, 0.123) );  //bool(false)
```

Comment: What does “the factor must be a multiple of the floating point accuracy” mean? What is the “floating point accuracy”?

Comment: floating point accuracy or floating point precision see https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php

Comment: There is no number defined at that link as “floating point accuracy” or “floating point precision”. The phrase “a multiple of the floating point accuracy” is meaningless.

Comment: The float precision (which is set as precision in php.ini) is 14 decimal places by default.